# @middy/http-json-body-parser can't parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Hello I want parsing a JSON so I used middy middleware to take about it. But it won't work. The data which need parsing can't processing to dynamodb. I was install @middy/http-json-body-parser, @middy/http-event-normalizer, @middy/http-error-handler but still won't work. Here is my code.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import middy from '@middy/core';
import httpJsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser';
import httpEventNormalizer from '@middy/http-event-normalizer';
import httpErrorHandler from '@middy/http-error-handler';
import createError from 'http-errors';

const nid = require('nid')({HEX:1, length:16})    

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function createAuction(event, context) {
  const { title, description } = event.body;
  const now = new Date();

  const auction = {
    id: nid(),
    title,
    description,
    status: 'OPEN',
    createdAt: now.toISOString(),
  };

  try {
    await dynamodb.put({
      TableName: process.env.AUCTIONS_TABLE_NAME,
      Item: auction,
    }).promise();
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 201,
    body: JSON.stringify(auction),
  };
}

export const handler = middy(createAuction)
  .use(httpJsonBodyParser())
  .use(httpEventNormalizer())
  .use(httpErrorHandler());
```

Here is screenshot in result.

[image: result]

Comment: What's the actual error? In can only see things that do work here. What do you expect vs. what do you get?

Comment: Title, and description can't input to my dynamodb sir, i don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue has nothing to do with dynamodb. `title` and `description` aren't event parsed by middy most likely because the request is not content-type application/json or api gateway is not configured properly. Impossible to say with so little information, but you should `console.log(event)` just after `async function createAuction(event, context) {` and see if it does contain anything useful from your request.

Comment: Yea I configure a mistake request in postman as Text not as JSON. thanks for helping!

Comment: I've updated the docs for middy (v2) to highlight the required content type.